Authentication on a GCP Cloud Function from an AWS Lambda using GCP Service Account Impersonation
I'm working on making a call from an AWS Lambda (within a VPC) to a GCP Cloud Function, but I'm struggling to find a solution that allows me to authenticate this call from Lambda.
We are not using GCP service account keys; instead, we have set up impersonation via AWS roles on GCP. Specifically, we have a Workload Identity Pool with an identity pool referencing Lambda's role.
I've found several code examples of how to declare a GCP token, but without success.
Has anyone implemented this type of authentication before, and if so, how?
def create_gcp_access_token(credentials):
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    credentials.refresh(request)
    access_token = credentials.token
    return access_token
   
target_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

credentials, project = google.auth.default(scopes=target_scopes)
print(f"credentials : {credentials}")
print(f"project : {project}")

access_token = create_gcp_access_token(credentials)
print(f"AccessToken : {access_token}")

print_gcp_project_info(gcp_project_id, access_token)


